# Obtain Transfer Function from Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

How would I go about obtaining the transfer function of the circuit below? I have seen some examples that use a voltage source, but none with a current source. Would I first obtain the impedance of the 3 components in parallel? What would V_in be? V_out is measured across R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feflw0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I believe if I convert the current source to a voltage source the schematic would look like the one below with R1 in series. Could I then obtain the transfer function as $$H(s) = \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{R_2||Z_{C1}}{Z_{tot}(s)} = \frac{\frac{1}{1/R_2+Cs}}{R_1+\frac{1}{1/R_2+Cs}}$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzc4jJ.png)</sup>

Comment: You can convert the current source into voltage source using Norton/Thevenin theorems.

Comment: *What would V_in be?* There is no \$V_{in}\$ indicated in the circuit. I do see a **current source**. Also think about R1 and R2 being in parallel.

Comment: What is output ? Input is current source (I), without prior knowledge of  output you cannot calculate transfer function !

Comment: I have edited my question based on the comments

Comment: There's no reason an input has to be a voltage source.  In electronics a current source is perfectly acceptable -- it's whatever the problem needs it to be.  In control theory inputs can be anything that affects a plant, and outputs can be any plant state.  So you may have a transfer function that has dimensions potatoes per gallon of diesel, or sewage tank level per second per pump RPM.

Comment: As hinted by TimWescott, your transfer function doesn't necessarily have to be Vout/Vin. In your question, the transfer function would be Vout/Iin expressed in ohm, just like you can find in a transimpedance amplifier where input is current and output is voltage.